# How to use 'map' with array in array (Json)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have JSON data:

```
users = [{
  "name": "alex", 
   "id":123, 
   "surname":"xx", 
    tarriff: {
      "id":1,
      "name":"free"
    }
},
 {
  "name": "tom", 
   "id":124, 
   "surname":"henry", 
    tarriff: {
      "id":1,
      "name":"free"
    }
}
```

]

I need to filter the data (remove "surname":"xx", "surname":"henry"  and smt else ).

If I use `tarriff.name` that's give syntax error

```
$scope.userfilter = users.map(({name,id, tarriff.name}) => ({name, id, tariff_name}));
```

help me please write the right solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and build a new object with [short hand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

```js
var users = [{ name: "alex", id: 123, surname: "xx", tarriff: { id: 1, name: "free" } }, { name: "tom", id: 124, surname: "henry", tarriff: { id: 1, name: "free" } }],
    result = users.map(({ name, id, tarriff }) => ({ name, id, tarriff_name: tarriff.name }));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `users` variable is an object, not array. I assume this is just a mistake here and you want to know how to filter an array. You should use [filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/filter-method-array-javascript) method like this:

```js
const users = [
  {"name": "alex", "id":123, "surname":"xx", tarriff:{"id":1,"name":"free"}},
  {"name": "emma", "id":123, "surname":"yy", tarriff:{"id":2,"name":"anna"}}
];

const criterium = "free";
const matchingUsers = users.filter(user => user.tarriff.name == criterium);

console.log (matchingUsers)
```

Answer (score 0):

it is hard to understand what you really want. but I am guessing that you are not talking about Array.filter and rather mapping deeply.

the syntax error is because you are de-structuring wrong. here is a better way :

```
$scope.userfilter = users.map( ({name, id, tarriff: { name: tarriff_name }}) => {
    return {name, id, tariff_name};
});
```